# IBM Cloud Watson and Local Data Connection

Tags: python, numpy, cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

How can I create a data connection between my Python environment in IBM Watson Studio and my local python program running on my computer? I'm aware of Cloud Object Storage API for uploading and downloading files, but what can I do to say upload a few integer variables or numpy array to the cloud environment to input into a function, then return those results back locally?

Comment: Cloud environment and function as in Python notebook or some Python function (IBM Cloud Functions, IBM Cloud Code Engine)?

Comment: @data_henrik Watson Studio Environment, pretty much like a Colab/Jupyter Python environment